# Open source firewall with multi wan support

Tags: network, firewalls, opensource

I use smoothwall express and also used IPCop. But now I need to have multi WAN support as I want to use a DSL and Cable internet connection together to increase my speed, specifically upload speed.

Any good user friendly recommendations out there?

Comment: Hi KKToronto, welcome to [security.se]! This question is not a good fit for our site - in general, questions should not be "list of X" type questions. Please see the [FAQ], and take a moment to read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

pfSense - http://www.pfsense.org - and Untangle - http://www.untangle.org both support multi-WAN configurations.  Smoothwall and m0n0wall may do so as well, but I don't have experience with them.